# How to use redirect in htaccess for a specific url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a client that sent a broadcast email with a bogus link in it, like this:

http://www.exampleclient.com/%22http:/www.intendedsite.com

I'm trying to patch their .htaccess file on the server to handle this.  Basically, if the url requested contains "www.intendedsite.com", I want to redirect the traffic to http://www.intendedsite.com.

I've tried a bizillion different RewriteCond/RewriteRule combinations, with no luck.  Anyone got good ideas for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (www\.intendedsite\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1/? [L,R=301]
```